# Configure VGA colors linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, vga, console

The colors in the Ubuntu terminal is "wrong". Is it possible to make it use the correct VGA colors. For comparison, here is a screenshot showing two VMs: one Xubuntu 16.04 (upper), and one Windows 98 (lower). I expected to see some options in console-setup, but that only covers the font, and character encoding.

[image: Console comparison]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux virtual console is based on VT102 and ECMA-48 terminal controls.  The `console_codes` and `console_ioctl` manpages give more information.  You can see the current colors in use with:

```
$ cat /sys/module/vt/parameters/default_{red,grn,blu}
0,170,0,170,0,170,0,170,85,255,85,255,85,255,85,255   # .../default_red
0,0,170,85,0,0,170,170,85,85,255,255,85,85,255,255    # .../default_grn
0,0,0,0,170,170,170,170,85,85,85,85,255,255,255,255   # .../default_blu
```

These give the RGB values for the main terminal colors (8 normal, 8 bright), in a comma-separated format (from the [`setvtrgb` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/setvtrgb.1.html)):

```
# default_red:  color0_R,color1_R,...,color15_R
# default_grn:  color0_G,color1_G,...,color15_G
# default_blu:  color0_B,color1_B,...,color15_B

+--------+--------+---------+
| Normal | Bright | Color   |
+--------+--------+---------+
|      0 |      8 | Black   |  
|      1 |      9 | Red     |  
|      2 |     10 | Green   |
|      3 |     11 | Yellow  |
|      4 |     12 | Blue    |
|      5 |     13 | Magenta |
|      6 |     14 | Cyan    |
|      7 |     15 | White   |  
+---------------------------+
```

---

To change them, first we need to save these values to a file:

```
$ cat /sys/module/vt/parameters/default_{red,grn,blu} > ~/myconsolecolors
```

Now tweak the colors using a basic text editor, and load the changes with `setvtrgb`.  Ubuntu installs the tool at `/sbin/setvtrgb` with the [kbd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kbd) package.

```
$ setvtrgb ~/myconsolecolors
```

---

Once that's all working to your satisfaction, you need to run it at system boot.  I'd copy your custom color file to somewhere handy in `/etc/`:

```
$ sudo cp ~/myconsolecolors /etc/custom-vt-colors
```

Then create a `systemd` unit to run it:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/custom-vt-colors.service

[Unit]
Description=Load custom VT color palette

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/setvtrgb /etc/custom-vt-colors

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally, enable and start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable custom-vt-colors.service
$ sudo systemctl start custom-vt-colors.service
```

Comment: discovering RGB values for the 16-color palette used by the OP's MS-DOS screenshot is left as an exercise for the reader. because reasons.

Comment: I love the brown hack.

Answer (score 2):

@quixotic's answer is very thorough and spot-on, and I thank quixotic greatly!

However, I discovered that in Ubuntu Mate 19.04, it gets overridden.  Essentially, there is already a service that loads a file by `setvtrgb`, and loads it very late.

What I did was follow the link from `/etc/vtrgb` to `/etc/console-setup/vtrgb`.  Edit or replace `/etc/console-setup/vtrgb`, keeping the same name, and all should work correctly, as described by quixotic.

(Note:  `setvtrgb.service`, which loads the linked-file from `/etc/vtrgb`, is located in `/lib/systemd/system/`.)